# Firebase - run "functions.https" in a cloud function when button clicked

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to get a firebase cloud function to run from clicking a button in HTML?

### html

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      This is some content
      <button onclick="exports.testName('testTxt')">click test</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

### index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.testName = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  res.status(200).send(`New Content`);
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's call callable function look at this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable